# Word for looking cute to try and get something from parents?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

Is there a word that describes the attitude of a child who is trying to get something from their parents, and so they try to look cute/sweet/innocent?

Comment: a word ... or a phrase?

Comment: puppy-dog eyes?

Comment: @lbf There’s a word for it in Persian and possibly Indian, so I’m curious if there’s a single word in English that works.

Comment: It's a specific form of what we would call "manipulation".

Answer (score 1):

**endearingly**

OED (for endearing):  That endears:  (a) that wins or inspires affection

from [Bertie Rides Again](https://books.google.com/books?id=y8RNupwb3osC&pg=PA110&dq=looked+at+her+endearingly&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ88PZ9YrjAhXPTd8KHcelCEwQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=looked%20at%20her%20endearingly&f=false)

> He looked at her endearingly and pleaded with all his rabbit might not
>   to be taken to the car. Mum could not resist his little face, but
>   strongly warned him that any more trouble and he would be in the car
>   ...